# How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping

Tags: html, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

When I scrape several related nodes from HTML or XML to extract the text, all the text is joined into one long string, making it impossible to recover the individual text strings.

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>baz</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').text # => "foobarbaz"
```

But what I want is:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

The same happens when scraping XML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
  <block>
    <entries>foo</entries>
    <entries>bar</entries>
    <entries>baz</entries>
  </block>
</root>
EOT

doc.search('entries').text # => "foobarbaz"
```

Why does this happen and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an easily solved problem that results from not reading the documentation about how `text` behaves when used on a NodeSet versus a Node (or Element).

The [NodeSet documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet:text) says `text` will:

> Get the inner text of all contained Node objects

Which is what we're seeing happen with:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>baz</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').text # => "foobarbaz"
```

because:

```
doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

Instead, we want to get each Node and extract its text:

```
doc.search('p').first.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.search('p').first.text # => "foo"
```

which can be done using `map`:

```
doc.search('p').map { |node| node.text } # => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Ruby allows us to write that more concisely using:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

The same things apply whether we're working with HTML or XML, as HTML is a more relaxed version of XML.

A Node has several aliased methods for getting at its embedded text. From [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method):

> `#content ⇒ Object`
>
> Also known as: `text`, `inner_text`
>
> Returns the contents for this Node.